# Swift UITableView Update Section Title and Row Content

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an app that contains buttons and a tableview, I want once I click on a button, the section title would change and the content of it would change, I don't want to use many number of sections or many number of rows.
Just one section and one row that would change their content upon each click. The problem is that it doesnt display but the "Test" as section Title and nothing else.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    var key = Int()
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
    // do not display empty `Section`s

    if(key == 1) {
        return "Monthly Usage"
    }
    if(key == 2) {
        return "Monthly Remaining"
    }
    if(key == 3) {
        return "Current Package"
    }
    return "Test"
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    // Configure the cell...

    switch(key) {
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = Data["Monthly_Usage"]
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = Data["Monthly_Remaining"]
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel?.text = Data["Monthly_Max"]
    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}


@IBAction func Monthy_Usage() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 1
    }
    else {
        key = 1
    }
    println(key)
}
@IBAction func Monthy_Remaining() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 2

    }
    else {
        key = 2
    }
    println(key)
}
@IBAction func Current_Package() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 3
    }
    else {
        key = 3
    }
    println(key)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Just solved it, I had to do tableView.reloadData() in every IBAction func

Comment: set default text in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath'. Does it always go to default in your switch,case fun.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten that I need to reload the data everytime I click, so that's how I solved it:

```
    @IBAction func Monthy_Usage() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 1
    }
    else {
        key = 1
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    println(key)
}
@IBAction func Monthy_Remaining() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 2

    }
    else {
        key = 2
    }
    println(key)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
@IBAction func Current_Package() {
    if tableView.hidden == true {
        tableView.hidden = false
        key = 3
    }
    else {
        key = 3
    }
    println(key)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```